# Class implements Runnable but start() and sleep() methods are not defined

Tags: java, multithreading, interface, sleep, runnable

I've created a class called `Thread` that implements `Runnable` but I cannot invoke the `start()` or `sleep()` methods for some reason. Any time I attempt to do so, I get errors saying that these methods are undefined for the class and suggests that I create them. So I created a new project and copied a sample code to see if there was something wrong with my own code and I received the same errors. Here's the sample code:

```
class Thread implements Runnable {
    private int a;
    public Thread (int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; ++i) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is " + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my own code:

```
public class Thread extends PID implements Runnable {
    public Thread() {};                      // Empty constructor for thread object
    public void run() {
        Random gen = new Random();           // Generates random values
        int sleepTime;                       // Sleep time
        sleepTime = gen.nextInt(60 - 1) + 1; // Generates random sleep time between 1 and 60 seconds
        try {
            Thread.sleep();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        System.out.println("The thread has been terminated");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are hiding the `Thread` class with your own `Thread` class. Rename your class to `MyThread` or whatever and the error will disappear.

Comment: @jlordo: post that as an answer.

Comment: @jlordo Makes perfect sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: Like many SO questions, it leaves me wanting to know why the OP decided to do that.

Comment: @jlordo: lol Sorry, I'm kinda new. Your answer's been accepted!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fix your current error, simply rename your `Thread` class to `MyThread` (or whatever), because your `Thread` class is hiding the `java.lang.Thread` class.

If you want to stick to `Thread`, you'll have to use the fully qualified name for `java.lang.Thread` like this:

```
try{
    java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mistakes**

1. Change class name from `Thread` to `MyThread`.
2. `run()` is called when you invoke `start()`. Invoke `start()` using class object.
3. `Thread.sleep();` needs an argument say, `sleepTime`

Here is the code of what I think you want to do. Tested on Eclipse Juno JDK 1.7

```
import java.util.Random;

class NewThread implements Runnable {

    public NewThread () {
    }
    public void run() {
        Random gen = new Random();           // Generates random values
        int sleepTime;                       // Sleep time
        sleepTime = gen.nextInt(60 - 1) + 1; // Generates random sleep time between 1 and 60 seconds

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } 
        System.out.println("The thread has been terminated");
    }
}

class MyThread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewThread t = new NewThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t);
        t1.start();

    }
}
```

**Output**

The thread has been terminated

Answer (score 0):

Interface Runnable do not have methods start() and sleep(), so be carefull with it. Interface Runnable only have run() method, and Java API recommends " the Runnable interface should be used if you are only planning to override the run() method and no other Thread methods." 
See Java API's Runnable documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html
In every other cases, your class should extned class Thread.